# Catkin Problems on sourcing workspaces

Tags: ros, source, bash, catkin-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am currently trying to source multiple catikin workspaces but I mostly get only one to work, which is the
last one I include.

What is the problem there?

It was working most of the time but, right now it does not anymore.
When it was working I always had to include one workspace after another one.
If I reverted the order only one of them was found.

But now I am always getting only one workspace to work.

Any idea what's the reason for that?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204843/catkin-problems-on-sourcing-workspaces/) by [LucianTM](https://answers.ros.org/users/21714/luciantm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2015-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It should never have worked with multiple workspaces.
You can only source one workspace at a time.

If you want to use multiple workspaces in one, you have to overlay these, i.e. source the dependent workspace at built time before the first build.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LucianTM](https://answers.ros.org/users/21714/luciantm/) on 2015-03-12**:
Ah yes I found that out now too, I need to source the one first which was built first. Because the second one depends on the first one when it was sourced on build time. I just adjusted my build script for that and now it seems to work.